# Can we run jquery spellchecker by badsyntax using asp.net web services?

Tags: jquery-plugins, spell-checking

I have been researching for quite a while now for an appropriate spell checker for textbox and multiline textbox.

I can see that this functionality is built in for firefox but its not present in chrome.

I was checking out all the demos for spellcheck which is provided by 
jquery spellchecker - badsyntax and i find it really nice and useful.

here is the link
http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/

But my problem here is- spellchecker makes use of php webservices and i want to use it in my ASP.net Webapplication.

is there any work around so that i can run it using asp.net web services?

Please provide me with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for the issue and
below is the webservice which returns the JSON response for the jquery spell checker

This code is the modified verion of code found in

github.com/jackmyang/jQuery-Spell-Checker-for-ASP.NET

```
     /// <summary>


  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Text;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Xml;

< %@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="JQuerySpellCheckerHandler2" %>



/// <summary>
/// jQuery spell checker http handler class. Original server-side code was written by Richard Willis in PHP.
/// This is a version derived from the original design and implemented for ASP.NET platform.
/// 
/// It's very easy to use this handler with ASP.NET WebForm or MVC. Simply do the following steps:
///     1. Include project jquery.spellchecker assembly in the website as a reference
///     2. Include the httphandler node in the system.web node for local dev or IIS 6 or below
/// <example>
///     <![CDATA[
///         <system.web>
///             <httpHandlers>
///                 <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="jquery.spellchecker.JQuerySpellCheckerHandler" path="JQuerySpellCheckerHandler.ashx"/>
///             </httpHandlers>
///         </system.web>
///     ]]>
/// </example>
///     3. If IIS7 is the target web server, also need to include the httphandler node in the system.webServer node
/// <example>
///     <![CDATA[
///         <system.webServer>
///             <handlers>
///                 <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" name="JQuerySpellCheckerHandler" type="jquery.spellchecker.JQuerySpellCheckerHandler" path="JQuerySpellCheckerHandler.ashx"/>
///             </handlers>
///         </system.webServer>
///     ]]>
/// </example>
///     4. On the web page which included the spell checker, set the 'url' property to '~/JQuerySpellCheckerHandler.ashx'
/// <example>
///     <![CDATA[
///         $("#text-content")
///             .spellchecker({
///                 url: "~/JQuerySpellCheckerHandler.ashx",
///                 lang: "en",
///                 engine: "google",
///                 suggestBoxPosition: "above"
///         })
///     ]]>
/// </example>
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Manipulations of XmlNodeList is used for compatibility concern with lower version of .NET framework,
/// alternatively, they can be simplified using 'LINQ for XML' if .NET 3.5 or higher is available.
/// </remarks>
public class JQuerySpellCheckerHandler2 : IHttpHandler
{
    #region fields

    // in case google changes url, value of GoogleSpellCheckRpc can be stored in web.config instead to avoid code re-compilation
    private const string GoogleSpellCheckRpc = "https://www.google.com/tbproxy/spell?";
    private const string GoogleFlagTextAlreadClipped = "textalreadyclipped";
    private const string GoogleFlagIgnoreDups = "ignoredups";
    private const string GoogleFlagIgnoreDigits = "ignoredigits";
    private const string GoogleFlagIgnoreAllCaps = "ignoreallcaps";

    #endregion

    #region properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [ignore duplicated words].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [ignore dups]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    private bool IgnoreDups { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [ignore digits].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [ignore digits]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    private bool IgnoreDigits { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [ignore all capitals].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [ignore all caps]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    private bool IgnoreAllCaps { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether [text alread clipped].
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if [text alread clipped]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    private bool TextAlreadClipped { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IHttpHandler

    /// <summary>
    /// Enables processing of HTTP Web requests by a custom HttpHandler that implements the <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpHandler"/> interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">An <see cref="T:System.Web.HttpContext"/> object that provides references to the intrinsic server objects (for example, Request, Response, Session, and Server) used to service HTTP requests. 
    /// </param>
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string engine = context.Request.Form[1];
        string lang = context.Request.Form["lang"];
        string text = context.Request.Form[3];
        string suggest = context.Request.Form[2];
        SetSwitches(context);            
        string result = SpellCheck(text, lang, engine, suggest);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/js";
        string jsonStr = "{\"outcome\":\"success\",\"data\":[" + result + "]}";
        if (suggest == "get_incorrect_words")
        {
            context.Response.Write(jsonStr);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Write(result);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether another request can use the <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpHandler"/> instance.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// true if the <see cref="T:System.Web.IHttpHandler"/> instance is reusable; otherwise, false.
    /// </returns>
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion

    #region private methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Spells the check.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="lang">The lang.</param>
    /// <param name="engine">The engine.</param>
    /// <param name="suggest">The suggest.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string SpellCheck(string text, string lang, string engine, string suggest)
    {
        if (0 == string.Compare(suggest, "undefined", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            suggest = string.Empty;
        }
        if (0 != string.Compare(engine, "google", true))
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Only google spell check engine is support at this moment.");
        }
        string xml;
        List<string> result;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(suggest) || suggest == "get_incorrect_words")
        {
            xml = GetSpellCheckRequest(text, lang);
            result = GetListOfMisspelledWords(xml, text);
        }
        else
        {
            xml = GetSpellCheckRequest(text, lang);
            result = GetListOfSuggestWords(xml, text);
        }
        return ConvertStringListToJavascriptArrayString(result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the boolean switch.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="queryStringParameter">The query string parameter.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool SetBooleanSwitch(HttpContext context, string queryStringParameter)
    {
        byte tryParseZeroOne;
        string queryStringValue = context.Request.QueryString[queryStringParameter];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryStringValue) && byte.TryParse(queryStringValue, out tryParseZeroOne))
        {
            if (1 < tryParseZeroOne || 0 > tryParseZeroOne)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Query string parameter '{0}' only supports values of 1 and 0.", queryStringParameter));
            }
            return tryParseZeroOne == 1;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of suggest words.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The source XML.</param>
    /// <param name="suggest">The word to be suggested.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<string> GetListOfSuggestWords(string xml, string suggest)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(suggest))
        {
            return null;
        }
        // 
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
        if (!xdoc.HasChildNodes)
        {
            return null;
        }
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("//c");
        if (null == nodeList || 0 >= nodeList.Count)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            list.AddRange(node.InnerText.Split('\t'));
            return list;
        }
        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the list of misspelled words.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">The source XML.</param>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static List<string> GetListOfMisspelledWords(string xml, string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xml) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return null;
        }
        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
        xdoc.LoadXml(xml);
        if (!xdoc.HasChildNodes)
        {
            return null;
        }
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes("//c");
        if (null == nodeList || 0 >= nodeList.Count)
        {
            return null;
        }
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {
            int offset = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["o"].Value);
            int length = Convert.ToInt32(node.Attributes["l"].Value);
            list.Add(text.Substring(offset, length));
        }
        return list;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the request URL.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text which may contain multiple words.</param>
    /// <param name="lang">The language.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ConstructRequestUrl(string text, string lang)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        lang = string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang) ? "en" : lang;
        return string.Format("{0}lang={1}&text={2}", GoogleSpellCheckRpc, lang, text);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the C# string list to Javascript array string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The list.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static string ConvertStringListToJavascriptArrayString(ICollection<string> list)
    {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        stringBuilder.Append("[");
        if (null != list && 0 < list.Count)
        {
            bool showSeperator = false;
            foreach (string word in list)
            {
                if (showSeperator)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append(",");
                }
                stringBuilder.AppendFormat("\"{0}\"", word);
                showSeperator = true;
            }
        }
        stringBuilder.Append("]");
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the switches.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    private void SetSwitches(HttpContext context)
    {
        IgnoreAllCaps = SetBooleanSwitch(context, GoogleFlagIgnoreAllCaps);
        IgnoreDigits = SetBooleanSwitch(context, GoogleFlagIgnoreDigits);
        IgnoreDups = SetBooleanSwitch(context, GoogleFlagIgnoreDups);
        TextAlreadClipped = SetBooleanSwitch(context, GoogleFlagTextAlreadClipped);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Requests the spell check and get the result back.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
    /// <param name="lang">The language.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string GetSpellCheckRequest(string text, string lang)
    {
        string requestUrl = ConstructRequestUrl(text, lang);
        string requestContentXml = ConstructSpellRequestContentXml(text);
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestContentXml);

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        try
        {
            byte[] response = webClient.UploadData(requestUrl, "POST", buffer);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs the spell request content XML.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text">The text which may contain multiple words.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string ConstructSpellRequestContentXml(string text)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); // Create the XML Declaration, and append it to XML document
        XmlDeclaration declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
        doc.AppendChild(declaration);
        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("spellrequest");
        root.SetAttribute(GoogleFlagTextAlreadClipped, TextAlreadClipped ? "1" : "0");
        root.SetAttribute(GoogleFlagIgnoreDups, IgnoreDups ? "1" : "0");
        root.SetAttribute(GoogleFlagIgnoreDigits, IgnoreDigits ? "1" : "0");
        root.SetAttribute(GoogleFlagIgnoreAllCaps, IgnoreAllCaps ? "1" : "0");
        doc.AppendChild(root);
        XmlElement textElement = doc.CreateElement("text");
        textElement.InnerText = text;
        root.AppendChild(textElement);
        return doc.InnerXml;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Also you can use this javascript:

```
      // Replace the Spellchecker.php path with Asp.net ashx path

    spellchecker = new $.SpellChecker(body, {
        lang: 'en',
        parser: 'html',
        webservice: {
          path: "../Includes/JS/spellify/JQuerySpellCheckerHandler2.ashx",
          driver: 'google'
        },
        suggestBox: {
          position: 'below'
        }
      });

      // Bind spellchecker handler functions
      spellchecker.on('check.success', function() {
        alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
      });

      spellchecker.check();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the plugin and would really like to incorporate some other webservice implementations.

This popped up recently in my google alerts, I can't verify it works though:

- http://www.yodotnet.com/post/2013/02/24/Jquery-Spellchecker-for-NET.aspx
- https://github.com/AnthonyTerra/ASP.MVC-Jquery-Spellchecker

Comment: Thank you for replying badsyntax. I really appreciate all the work you have put into your plugin. This plugin has shaped out really good. If we somehow implement it for ASP.net web service its just going to be Great. I am working on it. If i get a break through i ll surely share the code. Also please let me know what are the parameters taken by the php web service and whats the response we get from it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys: Veerendra Prabhu, badsyntax; I've integrated Nhunspell and asp.net Web Service (.asmx) and currently I'm trying to integrate jquery spellchecker - badsyntax to the proyect, I'm jquery spellchecker now conects with my web services but Im still dealing whith the returned data type of my web service to allow jquery spellcheker does its magic, but I thinks its something.

I took ideas from:

deepinthecode.com

Here are some ideas that I used:

I used [NHusnpell](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/nhunspell-net-spell-checker.aspx) that helps to get the incorrect words within a passed text and look into the [dictionary](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/dictionary) (open office downloaded as .oxt but you have to chante to zip to get en_US.aff, and en_US.dic) this files needs to be at bin directory.

At Glabal.asax file I created a static instance of NHuspell that does all the work.

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    static SpellEngine spellEngine;
    static public SpellEngine SpellEngine { get { return spellEngine; } }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string dictionaryPath = Server.MapPath("Bin") + "\\";
            Hunspell.NativeDllPath = dictionaryPath;

            spellEngine = new SpellEngine();
            LanguageConfig enConfig = new LanguageConfig();
            enConfig.LanguageCode = "en";
            enConfig.HunspellAffFile = dictionaryPath + "en_us.aff";
            enConfig.HunspellDictFile = dictionaryPath + "en_us.dic";
            enConfig.HunspellKey = "";
            //enConfig.HyphenDictFile = dictionaryPath + "hyph_en_us.dic";
            spellEngine.AddLanguage(enConfig);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (spellEngine != null)
                spellEngine.Dispose();
        }
    }

    ...

    protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (spellEngine != null)
            spellEngine.Dispose();
        spellEngine = null;

    }
}
```

Then I created an ASMX web service for the Get_Incorrect_Words and Get_Suggestions methods

```
 /// <summary>
/// Summary description for SpellCheckerService
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]    
[ScriptService()]
public class SpellCheckerService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{      

    [WebMethod]
    //[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string get_incorrect_words(string words)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> IncorrectWords = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        List<string> wrongWords = new List<string>();

        var palabras = words.Split(' ');

        // Check spelling of each word that has been passed to the method
        foreach (string word in palabras)
        {
            bool correct = Global.SpellEngine["en"].Spell(word);

            if (!correct){

                wrongWords.Add(word);
            }
        }

        IncorrectWords.Add("data", wrongWords[0]);

        return wrongWords[0];
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public List<string> get_suggestions(string word)
    {
        List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
        suggestions = Global.SpellEngine["en"].Suggest(word);
        suggestions.Sort();
        return suggestions;
    }
```

And Finally I modified the calls to the get_incorrect_words and get_suggestions in jquery.Spellchecker.js

```
 /* Config
   *************************/

  var defaultConfig = {
    lang: 'en',
    webservice: {
        path: 'SpellCheckerService.asmx/get_incorrect_words'
      //,driver: 'LabNET'
    },
    local: {
      requestError: 'There was an error processing the request.',
      ignoreWord: 'Ignore word',
      ignoreAll: 'Ignore all',
      ignoreForever: 'Add to dictionary',
      loading: 'Loading...',
      noSuggestions: '(No suggestions)'
    },
    suggestBox: {
      numWords: 5,
      position: 'above',
      offset: 2,
      appendTo: null
    },
    incorrectWords: {
      container: 'body', //selector
      position: null //function
    }
  };

  var pluginName = 'spellchecker';

...

     /* Spellchecker web service
   *************************/

  var WebService = function(config) {

    this.config = config;

    this.defaultConfig = {
      url: config.webservice.path,
      //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'text',
      cache: false,
      data: JSON.stringify({
        lang: config.lang,
        driver: config.webservice.driver
      }, null,2) ,
      error: function() {
        alert(config.local.requestError);
      }.bind(this)
    };
  };

  WebService.prototype.makeRequest = function(config) {

    var defaultConfig = $.extend(true, {}, this.defaultConfig);

    return $.ajax($.extend(true, defaultConfig, config));
  };

  WebService.prototype.checkWords = function (text, callback) {
      //action: 'get_incorrect_words',
      //JSON.stringify({

      //    text: text
      //}, null, 2)

      return this.makeRequest(
          {
              data: { words: text },
              success: callback
    });
  };

  WebService.prototype.getSuggestions = function (word, callback) {
      //action: 'get_suggestions',
    return this.makeRequest({
        data: JSON.stringify({

        word: word
      }, null, 2),
      success: callback
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi Victor.. I ll check with the code you provided and see how it works out.. Thanks

Comment: I've found out that jquery spellchecker expects from the web service as returned data an json in the following format : "{'outcome':'success','data':["incorrectoWord01, incorrectoWord02"]}" for the method that return mispelled words and a data as response in the ["suggest01, suggest02"] format for the suggestions words returned for the method that retrieves the seggestions

Comment: Victor thanks a lot.. I checked the same using firebug :).. and i have modified the code by https://github.com/jackmyang/jQuery-Spell-Checker-for-ASP.NET to work with jquery-spellchecker which was given be badsyntax. I ll share the code shortly